# Deserialize a JSON stream

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, json-deserialization

here's my class

```
[DataContract]
public class WytypowaneMecze
{
    public WytypowaneMecze() { }
    public WytypowaneMecze(String data, String d_gospodarzy, String d_gosci, String wynik)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.D_gospodarzy = d_gospodarzy;
        this.D_gosci = d_gosci;
        this.Wynik = wynik;
    }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string D_gospodarzy { get; set; }
    public string D_gosci { get; set; }
    public string Wynik { get; set; }
}
```

}

that's how i write to file my list wytypowane

```
    private async void zapiszPlik() 
    {
        string json = "wytypowane.json";
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<WytypowaneMecze>));

        var stream = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(json, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        using (stream)
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, wytypowane);
        }

    }
```

but i can't read this...

Additional information: '{}][{},{}][{}][{}][{},{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]' is not a valid JSON primitive. This error can also occur when extraneous data is present after the JSON data.

```
    private async void odczyt()
    {
        string json = "wytypowane.json";
        List<WytypowaneMecze> lista = new List<WytypowaneMecze>();
        var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<WytypowaneMecze>));
        var stream = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(json);
        using (stream)
        {
            lista = (List<WytypowaneMecze>)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception so you get? And is your json file's Build action set to content?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.WEB.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: '{}][{},{}][{}][{}][{},{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]' is not a valid JSON primitive. This error can also occur when extraneous data is present after the JSON data.

Comment: The error is not within your file access, but in your json serialization. Please check what data you are giving to the serializer. Seems like you are putting lots of empty values in there.

Comment: in first step im giving only one object:

        private void wytypujMecz(PrzyszleMecze mecz, String wynik) 
        {
            WytypowaneMecze nowyMecz = new WytypowaneMecze(mecz.Data, mecz.D_gospodarzy, mecz.D_gosci, wynik);
            wytypowane.Add(nowyMecz);
            zapiszPlik(nowyMecz);

        }

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the properties you want to serialize with the [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.  That's because you are using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` and data contracts are [opt-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Apply the DataMemberAttribute attribute in conjunction with the DataContractAttribute to identify members of a type that are part of a data contract. One of the serializers that can serialize data contracts is the DataContractSerializer.
>
> The data contract model is an "opt-in" model. Applying the DataMemberAttribute to a field or property explicitly specifies that the member value will be serialized. In contrast, the BinaryFormatter serializes public and private fields of a type, and the XmlSerializer serializes only public fields and properties of a type.

Thus:

```
[DataContract]
public class WytypowaneMecze
{
    public WytypowaneMecze() { }
    public WytypowaneMecze(String data, String d_gospodarzy, String d_gosci, String wynik)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.D_gospodarzy = d_gospodarzy;
        this.D_gosci = d_gosci;
        this.Wynik = wynik;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string D_gospodarzy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string D_gosci { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Wynik { get; set; }
}
```